# How to serve resx file in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, localization, resx

How can i serve a locale appropriate `.resx` file to a http client in ASP.NET?

e.g.

```
GET /App_LocalResources/MeshModdler.resx
```

### Background

i have a client-side binary that needs to ask a web-server for the appropriate language resources (i.e. it does not have all possible translations; it asks for the one it needs).

Right now the client-side binary prefers to be given an **xml** file containing all the localized resources (strings, etc). This XML file has a format that looks curiously like Microsoft's `resx` format (one might think the format was copied - and they would not be wrong).

Ideally we can use the power of an ASP.NET web-server to locate the appropriate resx file based on the http client's `Accept-Language`, e.g.

```
GET /App_LocalResources/MeshModdler.resx
Accept-Language: az-Cyrl-AZ
```

Ideally the web-server would try to return, in order of preference:

- `MeshModdler.az-Cyrl-AZ.resx`
- `MeshModdler.az-AZ.resx`
- `MeshModdler.az.resx`
- `MeshModdler.resx`

But instead the server returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

### Bonus Chatter

i know this is not possible. So in addition to a `cannot be done` answer, i would also accept an answer that just does what i want:

- harnesses the power of an ASP.NET web-server to perform resource resolution and fallback
- allows new localization `resx` files to be dropped into a folder and have them picked up
- will not require resorting to creating a dummy page that builds what *looks* like a `resx` file, but has to thunk every entry with:

  ```
  <root> 
     <data name="TesselateMesh.Caption">
         <value><%$ Resources:MeshModdler, TesselateMesh.Caption1 %></value>
     </data>
     ...
  </root>
  ```

### Additional Chatter

The hack for now will be to rename the `resx` files to `xml`:

- `MeshModdler.az-Cyrl-AZ.xml`
- `MeshModdler.az-AZ.xml`
- `MeshModdler.az.xml`
- `MeshModdler.xml`

And re-invent the fallback code:

```
GET /MeshModdler.az-Cyrl-AZ.xml
404 Not found

GET /MeshModdler.az-AZ.xml
404 Not found

GET /MeshModdler.az.xml
200 Ok
```

But it would be nice to work *with* ASP.NET, not against it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an ASHX file that takes a resource name file and looks up the correct `.ResX` file on the server.  (moving your current fallback logic to `/GetResource.ashx?Name=MeshModeler`)

Comment: How do i get the content for the response?

Comment: @IanBoyd: `Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/App_LocalResources/" + name))`

Comment: This works well, and is accepted. But anyone using it should be aware of the subtle bug that the encoding of the response doesn't match the encoding of the content. e.g. `MeshModdler-de-DE.resx` is encoded with code-page `850` (because they're Germany), then the carpet won't match the curtains.