# Download resource resx file of a visible aspx page from internet browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, resources

I have a simple question

Is it possible to download a specific resource file from a visible aspx page in my internet browser?

Just the way we do download .js (javascript) files.

I want to download Spanish (es-MX) resx file of a visible aspx page which is showing in spanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resx files aren't served up by the web server (which is a good thing, because some developers store things in there that should not be made public.)

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9267297/how-to-serve-resx-file-in-asp-net) describes how to create a handler that will output the contents of a resx file, where the variable 'name' is the filename of your resx file.

```
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/App_LocalResources/" + name))
```

EDIT: some extra detail

Having created your handler (let's call it GetResources.ashx), you would pass the filename to the handler using a querystring parameter. For example,

```
GetResources.ashx?name=Default.es-MX.resx
```

In the handler:

```
string name = Request.QueryString["name"].ToString(); // but check for null etc.
```

It's not a good idea to have this handler on your production site in a public directory, so either password protect it, or remove it entirely from your release version.

Comment: how to pass filename to this function

Comment: That means we have to modify the code, Is it possible that we can achieve this by making changes in IIS?

Comment: Safely and with fewer consequences? No, I don't think so but perhaps someone has a different answer.